# Determine whether list2 contains objects for all the unique ids of list1 and whether these objects also contain specific elements

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 variable (day and time) and 2 lists of objects (list1 and list2);

```
ArrayList<Teacher> list1 = new Teacher<>();
list1.add(new Teacher(1, "Mary"));  //Tid, name
list1.add(new Teacher(2, "Anne")); 
....

ArrayList<Session> list2 = new Session<>();
list2.add(new Session(101, 1, "Monday", "2-4pm")); //Sid, Tid, day, time
list2.add(new Session(102, 1, "Tuesday", "2-4pm"));
list2.add(new Session(103, 2, "Monday", "9-11pm"));
....

String day = "Monday"
String time = "9-11am"
```

I want to check if all the teachers have classes on monday from 9-11am using the Tid and the given day and time)

This is what I tried - using streams

```
Predicate<Session> dayEquals = s -> s.getDay().equals(day);
Predicate<Session> timeEquals = s -> s.getTime().equals(time);
Predicate<Session> combinedCondition = dayEquals.and(timeEquals);


if (list2.stream().filter(s -> s.getTid() == t -> t.getTid).anyMatch(combinedCondition)) {
          System.out.println("All teachers are occupied");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java stream API for this task. Assuming you have appropriate getters in your `Teacher` and `Session` class. I don't understand your approach as the `combinedCondition` is missing but whatever it may be `anyMatch` shouldn't be used if the condition checks for all teachers of `list 1` to be present as per your question. You should use `allMatch` that checks if all the elements of `list 1` match the given predicate.

```java
// get all the teachers' id as set who have session on given day and time

Set<Integer> tidList =list2.stream()
                .filter(session -> (day.equals(session.day)
                        && time.equals(session.time)))
                .map(Session::getTid)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());


// check if all the teachers from list1 is in the above set.

boolean result = list1.stream()
                .map(Teacher::getId)
                .allMatch(tidList::contains);
```

Comment: The combinedCondition is the combination of the two predicates dayEquals and timeEquals. My bad I had given this predicate a different name earlier. I just edited that out

Comment: but that stream condition is only on `list2` in your code. If you want to check if all teachers are scheduled then the approach mentioned above should work.  According to my understanding, you want to check whether all the teachers in `list1` have scheduled sessions on `day` and `time`.

Comment: Yes, your approach works. Thank you for the answer!